# Add option to change chat user gravatars to a text list

Tags: feature-request, chat, usability

When there's a large number of folks in a chat room, and you need to scan to see who's about, the gravatar icons don't really scale past ten or so users.

Having to rollover each gravatar icon to see who's who in the "tool tip", and especially when these icons "fade" over time, makes it less useful and a bit ["mystery meat"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mystery%20meat%20buttons). Also when a user changes their gravatar that just adds to the difficulty identifying users.

Can we have a feature to change from icons to a plain old text list of display names?

Comment: Most gravatars don't scale well at that size anyways.  They should be flyouts, like on the main site, or or the same flyouts when you click on the link of the user in chat.

Comment: Why not an in-chat command that displays a list of active folk (people who sent a message within the last 20 minutes) to you?

Comment: @Purmou - why just the last 20mins? I want to be able to easily see at a glance everyone who's in the room (recently active or not), like I can do with any conventional chat room.

Comment: Wouldn't mind being able to collapse it altogether with a toggle